# Android Getting the contacts when clicked on to the edit text

Tags: android

I am trying to get the selected contact number form the phone book when a button is clicked.Could any me please tell me how to get the contact number to the edit text.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

// using **Content Provider** you can do it
There are some helper methods, particularly ContentUris.withAppendedId() and Uri.withAppendedPath(), that make it easy to append an ID to a URI. Both are static methods that return a Uri object with the ID added. So, for example, if you were looking for record 23 in the database of people contacts, you might construct a query as follows:

```
import android.provider.Contacts.People;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.database.Cursor;

// Use the ContentUris method to produce the base URI for the contact with _ID == 23.
Uri myPerson = ContentUris.withAppendedId(People.CONTENT_URI, 23);

// Alternatively, use the Uri method to produce the base URI.
// It takes a string rather than an integer.
Uri myPerson = Uri.withAppendedPath(People.CONTENT_URI, "23");

// Then query for this specific record:
Cursor cur = managedQuery(myPerson, null, null, null, null);
```

[refer this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html)